# how to add/remove any application's EXE programmatically

Tags: java, windows, registry, advanced-installer

If we would like to start some applications automatically we use to put them in start-up folder in windows environment, how to add/remove any application's EXE programmatically. i am using java for my application.

**Detail With Background:** Working on a desktop based application, and using [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) to create the installer for app, it is working fine, **issue is** we have an option to add/remove the short cut of app's EXE in order to start app on system start-up, The Advanced Installer gives option to add the EXE file into start-up but how to add/remove it using java, as its a java based application

I just need to get some idea about if i need to change some registry value or java file handling etc for doing this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use shortcuts in the Startup folder, then you can delete them by finding the reference to it via "`%USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`" then just do a `File.delete()`. You could write a *.bat file to do this for you too if it can't be done programaticaly in "Advanced Installer". If you want it to be a little more under-the-covers, the system also has startup items located in the registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Below is an example in regedit:
[image]

Comment: cant find start-up items in registry can you please help,

Comment: All the items in /run are startup items. Key doesn't matter, but value is the full path to your executable including arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule task by executing next command:

```
schtasks /create /tn "My App" /tr c:\apps\myapp.exe /sc monthly /d 15 /ru "System"
```

You can execute this command by [Runtime.getRuntime().exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM - most suitable account for this.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Java application I assume you are using the [java launcher from Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-java.html)? If so, all you need to do is to [create a shortcut for your EXE launcher](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html#files) and place it in the predefined folder "Startup" folder under "Start Menu" folder from Files and Folders page. The shortcut will be installed there when you install the package and removed on uninstall, and it will start your application when the machine boots the OS.

Comment: yes that is right, but i have an option in the application's settings where your can set if user wants to start the application on start-up. What if user UN-check that option, in that case i have to remove that short   cut form start-up, and need to put it there again if user again select the option,

Comment: In this case I recommend you go for the registry entry, as Domenic mentioned. But I recommend using HKCU instead of HKLM hive, because in HKCU you can right without admin rights and only for the current user, so the option will not affect other users from the machine. If you want to write under HKLM you need to have your application launched with the command "Run as administrator" otherwise the write operation will fail silently. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314866